# Android - sendBroadcast() and onReceive() - synchronous solution for interprocess communication

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, synchronous

I would like make a library that would do some intent send/receive stuff  in a synchronous way (from the client side). So that client of my library won't have to care about implementing receivers.

The library would send intent somewhere and receive the response. Then it would return the result to the client synchronously.

The Use case is to transport some data between my own applications using intents. Usually I use intents and receiver asynchronously (as they supposed to work), but this an exception for the rule.

Proposed solution (simplified!). Library:

```
public class Helper {
private Context context;
private BroadcastReceiver tempReceiver;
private int result = 0;

int getResult() {

    tempReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Helper.this.result = 1;
        }
    };
    context.registerReceiver(tempReceiver);
    context.sendBroadcast(/* ask for smth */);

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    context.unregisterReceiver(tempReceiver);
    return result; 
}
}
```

The client is an application that would like to get some data from the library, like that:

```
int timeout = 5000;
Helper lib = new Helper(timeout);
lib.getData();
```

What do you think about that? What are the threats? I understand that calling getReturn() would be blocking and cannot be called in GUI thread. The question if the sleep solution is acceptable.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend using `Thread.sleep`. You could use  [`Handler.postDelayed`](http://goo.gl/rYpyp) to do what you'd like 5 seconds later.

Comment: But as far as I know, postDelayed is asynchrounous, so it won't work in this example. Remember that this method has to freeze the client until the response is ready (like reading from the stream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you are already aware of the standard synchronous versus asynchronous trade-offs, and situations where they are advantageous and not so.

IMO, your approach is okay only if the broadcast is also sent by your own application. If you are interested in a system broadcast, then the 5 second delay could vary between acceptable and catastrophic. Imagine registering for a "photo taken" broadcast, and then 5 seconds later when the user is taking another photo, your synchronous call returns and you display something thus annoying the user no end.

Also, how do you propose to deal with cases where the Broadcast is not a one-time, but rather continuous in nature?

I had tried to design an API using `AsyncTask` under the covers; and to expose it in a synchronous way. But it turned out that the usage of this API would be much more confusing for client code. I concluded that certain things are just not meant to be done synchronously; and went ahead with a callback-based async approach. Point I'm trying to make is, Broadcasts are just not meant to be synchronous.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I have one specific use case where I want to use it.
I want Application1 to ask Application2 for some small data. And it's not supposed to be continuous, it's just one time request.

And yes, my application would broadcast the intent, and my other application would receive it and respond to it.

Comment: I see. In that case, you should be able to get away with this design. Do notice that the onus is now on the client code to handle a case where no data is available after the timeout expires. Contrast this with an async design where the client code would just be notified - whether data is available immediately; or after 10 seconds. Also, even if the data is available right away, the Application 1 is still delayed by 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I think I can make a loop:
`for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  Thread.sleep(100);
  if (result!=0) {
    break;
  }
}`
So that it would be more reponsive. Btw. I understand it'a kind of low level programming that has some issues, but in this case it'a all about making it easy for the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve exactly.
Who's the broadcaster? Who's the receiver? A better description of the communication between the library and the client code would be helpful.

Broadcasts are asynchronous anyway ([sendBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)). The receiver will be called on the UI Thread, that's where it acts *synchronously*. But it does not guarantee when it will be called. The android system will do that as soon as possible.

Synchronizing by a sleep seams like a really wrong design decision and it's not what broadcasts should be used for.

If you need a synchronous callback I would recommend the listener pattern, like android does: e.g. onClick interface.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried to explain this design a little bit in comments for techie.curious. 
Imagine that I would like wrap "sending intent" and "receiving response" into one blocking method (that would be used like blocking reading from the stream).

Comment: I see. It's a communication between applications. That's an important fact. You should mention that in your question. That would push the question more into "interprocess communication". I can't help you there because I never tried that before, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**basics !** - synchronization

```
public abstract class WorkerThread {

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        // loop 
        while(!isCanceled()) {
            try {
                //  wait() 
                waitUntilResumed():
                // when notified do work 
                doWork():
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // restore interrupted state 
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * main thread loop
     */
    protected abstract void doWork() throws InterruptedException;

    /**
     * blocks current thread until it is resumed
     */
    private synchronized void waitUntilResumed() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isPaused()) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    /**
     * resume thread 
     */
    public synchronized void resumeAction() {
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```